# When $\lambda$-commutativity implies commutativity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert $F$.

> Let $T,S\in\mathcal{B}(F)$. The pair $(T,S)$ is said to $\lambda$-commute if there exists $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $TS=\lambda ST$. I am looking for necessary and sufficient conditions on the operators $S$ and $T$ such that $(T,S)$ $\lambda$-commute, then they already commute.

I know already that $S,T \geq 0$ or $S,T \leq 0$ is a sufficient condition for $S$ and $T$ to commute if they $\lambda$-commute, but this is far from necessary.

Comment: In finite dimensions, tr(TS)=tr(ST), so if tr(TS) is non-zero, then $\lambda=1$.

Comment: I think you just want "if" in your guess, not "only if". The "only if" direction fails trivially, for example for any $S$ and $T$ which satisfy $TS \neq \lambda ST$ and $TS \not\geq 0$.

Comment: I guess the question is meant to be: Let $TS = \lambda ST$. Then $[T,S] = 0$ if and only if $TS \geq 0$ and $ST \geq 0$. By the way, $TS \leq 0$ and $ST \leq 0$ is also sufficient for $[T,S] = 0$ then, no?

Comment: Well, that version is also obviously false: you can certainly find $S$ and $T$ which commute but for which $TS \not\geq 0$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Do you think this equivalence is false: ($TS=\lambda ST\Longrightarrow [T,S]=0$) if and only if ($TS\geq 0$ and $ST\geq 0$) ? Thank you

Comment: @Schüler: yes, that is the version I falsified in my first comment.

Comment: The quantifiers are still confusing in this question. Are $T$, $S$ and $\lambda$ fixed at the start, or are they freely varying? I agree with previous comments by @NikWeaver

Comment: Yes, a definiteness assertion makes very little sense (see $S = T = (i,0;0,-i)$ as a specific example).

Comment: I think the question is: What is a necessary and sufficient condition on operators $S$ and $T$ such that ($T$ and $S$ $\lambda$-commute iff they  commute), is it true?

Comment: If $ST$ is not quasi-nilpotent and either $|\lambda| \neq 1$ or the spectrum of $ST$ (with or without zero) is not rotation invariant for every angle (including rational multiples of $\pi$), then $ST =\lambda TS$ is either impossible or entails $\lambda = 1$. I don't see what else can be said ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see which kind of condition you are looking for, as there are a lot of pairs $T,S$ such that $TS=\lambda ST$ and $\lambda\ne1$, even in finite dimension. Such pairs are said to $\lambda$-commute.

An interesting case happens when $\lambda$ is root of unity, say of order $r$. Then (Potter's Theorem) $(T+S)^r=T^r+S^r$.

Still when $\lambda^r=1$, here is a construction. Choose $T={\rm diag}(I_{n_1},\lambda I_{n_2},\ldots,\lambda^{r-1}I_{n_r})$ and $S$ a blockwise cyclic matrix
$$S=\begin{pmatrix} 0_{n_1} & M_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & & & \ddots & M_{r-1} \\
M_r & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0_{n_r} \end{pmatrix}.$$
This pair $\lambda$-commutes.

Comment: It is amazing how many lovely facts are in the world but of which I am completely ignorant.  For anyone else so ignorant, Potter's theorem apparently dates back to [Potter - On the latent roots of quasi-commutative matrices](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2306202) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=34745)).

Comment: Incidentally, this finite dimensional case is a lovely first instance of the general fact that semisimple centralisers in simply connected algebraic groups like $\mathrm{SL}_n$ are connected, but those in non-simply connected groups like $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ need not be.